# Applying many conditions in single REGEX sentence

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to extract some years and texts from an essay using REGEX in VB.NET;
and I am using VB.NET;

My Input is the one in my previous post and as below:

```
111-This is just the title and has no year or country:
222-Preamble with only year 1999 and no country:
333-I was born in 1990 in Canada, I was born to love, and be loved.
444-She was born in 2000 in Malaysia and she likes fishing.
555-My mother was born in South Africa and she love all her sons and daughters, she was born in 1960.
666-My Dad was born in a small village in France in 1955. He loves my Mom.
777-and finally thanks from USA, without a year.
```

I wrote the following code in VB.NET:

```
        Dim expression1 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d{3}-")
    Dim Mekdam1 As MatchCollection = expression1.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)
    For Each itemCode1 As Match In Mekdam1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemCode1)
    Next
    ListBox1.Items.Add("-------")
    Dim expression2 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d{4}")
    Dim Mekdam2 As MatchCollection = expression2.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)
    For Each itemCode2 As Match In Mekdam2
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemCode2)
    Next
    ListBox1.Items.Add("-------")
    Dim expression3 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\b(USA|Canada|Malaysia|France|South Africa)\b)")
    Dim Mekdam3 As MatchCollection = expression3.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)
    For Each itemCode3 As Match In Mekdam3
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemCode3)
    Next
    ListBox1.Items.Add("-------")
    Dim expression4 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d{3}-\d{4}(\b(USA|Canada|Malaysia|France|South Africa)\b)")
    Dim Mekdam4 As MatchCollection = expression4.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)
    For Each itemCode4 As Match In Mekdam4
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemCode4)
    Next
```

I am getting all the expected results except in the last loop;
THE LAST LOOP IS SUPPOSE TO SUM THE RESULTS OF THE FIRST 3 LOOPS;
the results are as below:

```
111-
222-
333-
444-
555-
666-
777-
-------
1999
1990
2000
1960
1955
-------
Canada
Malaysia
South Africa
France
-------
```

The last loop gave empty results BUT; I am expecting the following:

```
333--EXTRA1-1990-EXTRA2- Canada
444--EXTRA1-2000-EXTRA2- Malaysia
555--EXTRA1-1960-EXTRA2- South Africa
666--EXTRA1-1955-EXTRA2- France
```

Please NOTE that I am trying to add "-EXTRA1-" AND "-EXTRA2-" in the middle;
Any help appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem like you necessarily need a regex for it, does it? You're already grabbing the values out of the strings, so you could just store them and use them in your last loop. That might perform a bit better, but it'd definitely be easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the comment; I agree 100% with you and I was going to do it that way; but I just thought that there might be a single REGEX sentence that might do this. That way the code will be more concise and efficient.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. Not to mention, they're also a fun approach to take, usefulness aside. Unfortunately I'm no master of regexes. I agree that it sounds like something they'd be able to do, though.